# Branch.io has integration with nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, branch.io

I cannot se any docs or code on github with that integration.

Branch have integration with react-native, cordova, android Java, IOS and others tools, but i cannot see any documentation or lib related to NativeScript on the branch.io site or account on github.

My app is written in NS, can i use branch on my project?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Branch does not directly support integration with Native Script. You may still be able to integrate your application with Branch native SDK by building a bridging header or something similar, but Branch will not be able to provide any guidance on the integration.